# How to use g++ instead of clang in Macbook M1 and later

Tags: gcc, g++

I have seen a lot of people struggling with this problem, so I want to share this solution which works for me.

Please note that I have already installed `homebrew` via [brew.sh](https://brew.sh) and gcc using `brew`:

```
brew install gcc
```

I really hope this can help you if you are having the same problem as me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution is the solution I found working for mac M1 and above (I am using M2), from this blog: [codeforces.com](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/88063)

Firstly, I go to my `homebrew/bin`:

```
cd /opt/homebrew/bin/
```

Then, I link g++-12 (or g++-11..., whichever version of g++ you are using) to this directory:

```
ln -s g++-12 g++
```

This also solved the `bits/stdc++.h file not found` for me, because in my case, I compile c++ file inside vim and in vim, clang seems to overwrite g++.

In addition to this, if you want to not let clang overwrites gcc in zsh, add those to your `.zshrc`:

```
alias gcc="gcc"
alias g++="g++"
alias cc="cc"
alias c++="c++"
```

Note: you can edit .zshrc either by `nano .zshrc` or `vim .zshrc`.